# UWP Access MediaPlayerElement from other page

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

In my MainPage.xaml I have

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="navView">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="music" Content="My Music"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame x:Name="myFrame">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="nowPlaying"
          AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                ...
            </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        </MediaPlayerElement>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to play music (pass Uri) from other Page (MyMusic) but I can't find a way to access the MediaPlayerElement. The other Page is opened in myFrame. And I want to keep the TransportControls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on a UI element to play your media from another page. Instead, use the MediaPlayer class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayerelement-to-render-video-in-xaml

So specify your MediaPlayerElement (*make sure to set AreTransportControlsEnabled value to what you need it to be*):

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="_mediaPlayerElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Then you can link your element to the MediaPlayer object which you can reference in code:

```
_mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
```

Then play whatever you need:

```
_mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video.mkv"));
mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18220091)

Comment: Updated the answer.